# remove all elements in a list not relatively prime

Tags: python

I have a list `m` in python, and I want to remove all the elements in m that are not relatively prime to all previous elements. So if `m=[2,3,4]` I want the output to be `[2,3]`.

I tried iterating through the values of `m`, but it doesnt work since the size of `m` changes and then the index value is out of range.

Comment: Can you add the code that you are talking about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) within a list comprehension and use `fractions.gcd` function to get the gcd for each pairs :

```
>>> from fractions import gcd
>>> [j for i,j in enumerate(m) if not any(gcd(j,t)!=1 for t in m[:i])]
[3, 100, 7, 11, 17]
```

Also as @mgilson mentioned in comment as a more efficient way instead of simple slicing in `any` you can use `itertools.islice` function.

Comment: are you assuming sorted order?

Comment: It's possible that your `any` clause could be made more efficient by using `itertools.islice` rather than an actual list slice (though you'd have to `timeit` with real data to make any real claims)

Comment: I think this fails for m = [4,15,20,25]. Maybe need `gcd` from the `fractions` module.

Comment: @Kasramvd but gcd(a,b) > 1 doesn't imply that either a % b or b % a = 0

Comment: @mgilson Yeah, I'll add that too!

Comment: @JohnColeman That would be `or` I changed it and I think this will resolve the OP's need!

Comment: @Kasramvd The *definition* of relatively prime involves `gcd`. Why try to avoid it? Your examples fail on [4,6]. 6 isn't relatively prime to 4 -- so OP wants [4] but yours yields [4,6]

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes you are right, I'll update the question.thanks!

Comment: @Kasramvd -- *Now* your answer is worth an upvote. I always enjoy seeing elegant list comprehensions in Python.